# [KDB+/Q]: Deparse q parse tree into q expression (string)

Tags: parsing, kdb, q-lang

Let's define `deparse`<sup>1</sup> as *inverse* operation to q's native `parse`, so that the following holds:

```
q)aStringQExpression~deparse parse aStringQExpression
1b
```

**Question**

What's the definition of `deparse` function so that the above indeed works?

For example, in the  below update expression, we know that `"a*0^b+c-d"` expression corresponds to `` (*;`a;(^;0;(+;`b;(-;`c;`d)))) `` parse tree:

```
q)-3!parse "update col:a*0^b+c-d from t"
"(!;`t;();0b;(,`col)!,(*;`a;(^;0;(+;`b;(-;`c;`d)))))"
```

So the envisaged `deparse` function should return:

```
q)deparse "(*;`a;(^;0;(+;`b;(-;`c;`d))))"
"a*0^b+c-d"
q)deparse "(!;`t;();0b;(,`col)!,(*;`a;(^;0;(+;`b;(-;`c;`d)))))"
"update col:a*0^b+c-d from t"
```

**Motivation/Background/Use case:**
Inline expressions are arguably faster to [grok](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=grok) by human eye (left-to-right) than deeply nested parse trees. Although in the background my code is editing the parse tree programatically, it is useful for debugging or presentation to conveniently convert that resulting parse tree into inline expression string.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Similar functionality described here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Expressions.html#parsing-and-deparsing</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This `unparse` repository from Github](https://github.com/patmok/unparse/blob/master/unparse.q) solves the problem. Amazing:

```
q).unparse.unparse parse "update col:a*0^b+c-d from t"
"update col:(a*(0^(b+(c-d)))) from t"

q).unparse.unparse parse "a*0^b+c-d"
"(a*(0^(b+(c-d))))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this would be to parse the list recursively and build up a string, e.g. for a dyadic:

```
q)deparse:{a:-3!'x;a[1],a[0],a[2]}
q)deparse parse "3*3"
"3*3"
```

So you can count `last x` to get it valency and build the string accordingly

Comment: Eventually I got very lucky and stumbled by accident upon the complete solution on Github. See my answer, but many thanks!